# Newtonsoft.Json NullValueHandling=Ignore doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, json, null, json.net, decorator

C# with Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.2. I am deserializing a JSON string as such

```
var car = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(resp);
```

where resp looks like this:

```
{
    "perf": {
        "perfRef": null,
        "perfTest": {
            "value": 1.2,
            "unit": "percent"
        }
    }
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
public partial class perf
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("perfRef", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public PerfRef perfRef { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("perfTest", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public PerfTest perfTest { get; set; }

}
```

But I keep getting an exception

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'perfRef' expects a non-null value. Path 'perf'
```

I don't get why this is happening. I thought the `NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore` would override any 'Required' option. Am I just misinterpreting how the decorators work?

Comment: Try remove ```Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull``` ?

Comment: ok but why? I am trying to understand why. If I read the documentation right it says "Ignore null values when serializing and deserializing objects."

Comment: ```Required``` and ```NullValueHandling ``` are different property. Those will be check separately. You can check source code method ```EndProcessProperty()``` https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/d0a328e8a46304d62d2174b8bba54721d02be3d3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs

Comment: I believe null value handling is only relevant during serialization, not deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

you have `Required`  which means you cannot have a null value for the `perfRef`
property.

there are ways to solve this.

either remove `Required` or provide the value to this property or set the Required attribute to `AllowNull` or `Default`.

**Note**: `NullValueHandling` Ignore means that null values will be ignored when serializing and deserializing JSON.

Comment: So the two settings seem to contradict each other. There must be a hierarchy of which one wins. I think that's where I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the cause is that the json-string is wrapped with `{"Perf": {...}}` and you need an additional class to deserialize it.

My sample array `[...]` has two json-strings. Both contain the same object `{...}`

- the first wraps it with `{"Perf": {...}}` like your sample
- the second does not.

```json
[
{"Perf": {"perfRef":null, "perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}},        
         {"perfRef":null, "perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}
]
```

You can deserialize the first json string `json[0] = {"Perf": {"perfRef":null, "perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}}` using a class that acts as a wrapper (here `JsonResponse`):

```cs
// to deserialize 
// {"Perf": {"perfRef":null, "perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}}
public class JsonResponse{
    public Perf Perf {get; set;}
}

// use
JsonResponse resp0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(json[0]);
```

If the json-string would not be wrapped then there is no need for a wrapper class

```cs
// to deserialize json[1] 
// {"perfRef":null, "perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}

// use
Perf resp1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Perf>(json[1]);
```

This is a [lingpad](/questions/tagged/lingpad)-program that deserializes both json strings:

```cs
void Main()
{   
    // for {"Perf": {...}} a wrapper class is needed
    JsonResponse withWrap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(GetResp()[0]); 

    // for {...} not
    Perf noWrap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Perf>(GetResp()[1]); 
    withWrap.Dump("Object {...} wrapped in JsonResponse: {Perf: {...}}");
    noWrap.Dump("Object {...} not wrapped");
}
// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public string[] GetResp(){
    string[] responses = {""" 
        {"Perf":{"perfRef":null,"perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}}
        """, 
        """ 
        {"perfRef":null,"perfTest":{"value":"1.2","unit":"percent"}}
        """};
    return responses;
}
public class JsonResponse{
    public Perf Perf {get; set;}
}
public class PerfTest{
    public string? Unit {get; set;}
    public double? Value {get; set;}    
}
public class Perf{ 
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("perfRef")]
    public string PerfRef { get; set; }
    //public PerfRef perfRef { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("perfTest")]
    public PerfTest PerfTest { get; set; }
}
```

The result of the deserialized object `JsonResponse` and `Perf` are on the right side.

[image: linqpad newtonsoft serialize with wrapper JsonResponse]

Comment: It looks more like its the Required and NullValueHandling properties

Comment: Above you can see that my `deserialisation` works as expected - at least to my understanding. If the above result is not what you expect that it would be helfpfull if you could clarify what it is you are missing. What is missing from the above linqpad-solution?

Comment: To clarify further you wrote `But I keep getting an JsonSerializationException - Required property 'perfRef' expects a non-null value` and that you expects that the null option would override any 'Required' option.  What is your desired result? Do you want it to be required but also allow null values?

Comment: perfRef is not required and if it does exists in the JSON then it can be null.

Comment: If the property `perRef` is not required and can be null like this `{ "perRef": null, ... }` then i suggest that you remove `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("perfRef", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull`.